# Assert fires in boost::intrusive_ptr when used in a container

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have a Producer-Consumer arrangement to process events coming from the network. A `Dispatcher` gives work to multiple `EventHandler` threads via a mutex protected queue owned by the worker thread. The event objects placed in the queue use `boost::intrusive_ptr`

```
class Event { ... }
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Event> EventPtr;
```

The queue is a template defined as:

```
template<typename Data>
class ConcurrentQueue : boost::noncopyable
{
protected:
    std::queue<Data> _queue;
    boost::mutex _dataMutex;
    boost::condition_variable _dataAvailable;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void push(Data const& data)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_dataMutex);
        _queue.push(data);
        lock.unlock();
        _dataAvailable.notify_one();
    }
...
};
...
typedef ConcurrentQueue<EventPtr> EventQueue;
```

The `EventHandler` waits for an event to be put on its queue and when available removes it from the queue using the method `waitAndPop`:

```
void waitAndPop(Data& poppedValue)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_dataMutex);
    while(_queue.empty())
    {
        _dataAvailable.wait(lock);
    }
    poppedValue = _queue.front();
    _queue.pop();
}
```

This was working well but I then needed to ensure the `Dispatcher` gives related work to the same `EventHandler`. So I implemented a `waitAndPeek` method to leave the `Event` object on the queue but return the pointer to it.

```
void waitAndPeek(Data& peekedValue)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_dataMutex);
    while(_queue.empty())
    {
        _dataAvailable.wait(lock);
    }
    peekedValue = _queue.front();
}
```

Once precessing of the event is complete the event is popped off the queue. Leaving the event on the queue allows the Disptacher to check the item at the head of the queue to see if it is related to the one it is trying to allocate. (Done in a mutex protected way but not shown)

Here's the code extracting the pointer from the EventQueue:

```
EventPtr event;
// Loop, processing events placed on the queue.   
while (true)
{
    // Blocking call. Will halt the thread until there is work to do.
    _eventQueue->waitAndPeek(event);
    // Try to access event but ASSERT fires
    int id = event->getId();
    ...
}
```

The problem is an ASSERT is fired in the `intrusive_ptr` code when I use the peeked pointer.

```
/usr/local/packages/Boost/1.40.0/include/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:166:
T* boost::intrusive_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = Event]:
Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

As soon as I revert the code to use the `waitAndPop` method the problem goes away, what could be causing the ASSERT to fire just because I leave the event on the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at intrusive_ptr docs:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#indirection

In order to dereference it, it must hold a non-NULL pointer.

Comment: The `Event` object on the queue is non-null when I use the pop method to remove it. The trouble starts when I leave the object on the queue and try to use the pointer returned by `peek`. It's as though the ref count is being decremented even though I have a pointer to the object. I'm adding logging of the object use count to try to track down when it is incremented/decremented.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it turns out the event I was trying to use had been deleted, so you are correct in saying "... it must hold a non-NULL pointer."

The problem was nothing to do with the boost library or the use of intrusive_ptr in a collection. Embarrassingly it was due to a function which, in certain cases, cleared the queue of work when there is a problem with the current task. I still had a pointer to the event at the head of the queue (now deleted) so the code was using a deleted pointer and throwing the assert.